# Adding single annotation to multiple pages of PDF

Tags: swift, pdf, uiimageview, pdfkit, electronic-signature

I need to add a signature in two places on a two paged PDF, with a single annotation.  Currently,  the signature will go to both locations if the PDF is not scrolled.  If I do scroll, the signature(image) only goes on the current page.

```
func epSignature(_: EPSignatureViewController, didSign signatureImage: UIImage, boundingRect: CGRect) {
    print(signatureImage)

    signature = [signatureImage]

    userSignature = self.signature

    for index in 0..<pdfDocument.pageCount {
        if let page = pdfDocument.page(at: index){

            let annotations = page.annotations
            for annotation in annotations {

                    if annotation.fieldName == "CLIENT SIGNATURE" {
                            let bounds = annotation.bounds
                            let imageAnnotation = ImageAnnotation(imageBounds: bounds, imageOrientation: .up, image: userSignature[0])
                            page.addAnnotation(imageAnnotation)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to add a signature in two places on a two paged PDF, with a single annotation

According to the specification

> a given annotation dictionary shall be referenced from the **Annots** array of only one page

*(ISO 32000-1, section 12.5.2 "Annotation Dictionaries")*

Thus, your single annotation cannot be validly used on both pages.

On the other hand an annotation has only a single set of coordinates. On the same page, therefore, it can appear only in one place.

Thus, your need is impossible to fulfill in a valid pdf.

Comment: There's also a good statement about that thing in [this](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PPKAppearances.pdf) document: _The location of a signature within a document can have a bearing on its legal meaning. For this reason, signature fields never refer to more than one annotation. If more than one location is associated with a signature, the meaning may become ambiguous.[...]_

Comment: @JanSlabon indeed. That quote originally refers to signature fields (for cryptographic digital signatures) while the question here to me appears to refer to "image fields" (for a mere bitmap of an ink signatures). Nonetheless the reasoning applies.

Comment: @Jan Actually your quote found its way into ISO 32000-2 as *"The location  of  a signature within  a document  can  have a bearing  on  its  legal  meaning.  For  this  reason, signature fields  shall  never  refer  to  more than  one annotation."* *(section 12.7.5.5 Signature fields)*

Comment: I just read "signature" and then your reply which reminded me on this quote. Good to know that it made it into PDF 2, thanks for the info.